# Lookup Filter: How To Display No Result If Dependent Fields Are Empty And All Related Result if Dependent Fields Are Present

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter, dependent-lookup

I am setting up a lookup filter to meet the condition below under `Opportunity` object in a custom lookup field `PSource`:

1. If both Account and Contact is empty, then don't display result in lookup
2. If Account is only present, then display result related to Account only
3. If Contact is only present, then display result related to Contact only
4. If both Account and Contact is present, then display results related to both Account and Contact.

The filter conditions I have create so far are:

```
a PSource: Account ID EQUALS Opportunity: Account Name ID
b PSource: Contact ID EQUALS Opportunity: Contact ID
```

I've done `(1 AND 2) AND (1 OR 2)` and it worked for #1, #2, #3 but not on #4.

I've done `(1 OR 2)` and it worked only for #4, #3, #2, but not on #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team leader has solved the problem. Below are the filter conditions:

1. Opportunity: Account Name ID EQUALS PSource: Account ID
2. Opportunity: Contact ID EQUALS PSource: Contact ID
3. Opportunity: Account Name ID NOT EQUAL TO
4. Opportunity: Contact ID NOT EQUAL TO

And the filter logic is `(1 AND 3) OR (2 AND 4)`.

**Note:** `3` and `4` are where I went wrong. When I researched and saw `<blank>`, I thought I would literally put `<blank>`. Unfortunately, it simply means blank (don't put anything in the value field).

**Explanation:** With the filter logic above, because it is being `AND`, a field who is empty will automatically exclude the result of its filter. `OR` is used because the 2 fields are independent of each other, thus, if one is empty but the other is not empty, then result of non-empty field is being displayed, while the result of the empty field is excluded.

Comment: And had you put those details in your question you would have received an answer long ago

Comment: @Eric , sorry, but the details in my answers were based on the solution. There were not yet present during my question.

Comment: So you did not know the criteria you had for the lookup filter? The solution was because you had `<blank>` in the criteria. If you had posted the criteria you had, especially since it was directly related to your question, you would have received a quicker response. Just keep in mind for future questions. The more detail you give then better the chances for an answer

Comment: @Eric , sorry and thank you. I discard it earlier before posting the question because I thought it would not help.